# Aligning CarouselView across platform

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

How can I get iOS and Android the same? I've tried endless combinations.

On iOS I have got it perfect - when it first loads, the first image in sequence is dead centre on the screen, and there is just enough showing for PeekInsert for the next one. When you flip, they remain equal

On Android, I've failed to get the first image (when there is nothing to the 'left' of it) to be dead centre - if I want PeekInsert to show at all, I cannot seem to help it being offset. once you start flipping, so long as there is one either side, it works OK

I am using an image in a grid of 100* width and height, and then these parameters (so far - as I said Android isn't the same, I know my values are different as whatever happens the same inputs don't translate into same result on each platform, but iOS as I have written it here is 'correct')

```
        <CarouselView.PeekAreaInsets>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="50, 50, 50, 50" />
                    <On Platform="Android" Value="0,0,200,0" />
                </OnPlatform>
            </CarouselView.PeekAreaInsets>

                  <Grid.Padding>

                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
                                <On Platform="iOS" Value="10, 10, 10, 10" />
                                <On Platform="Android" Value="20, 20, 20, 20" />
                        </OnPlatform>


                  </Grid.Padding>
```

Comment: The code you provided could not make sure what cause the error. Please provide more code about the carouselView.

Comment: OK I was just trying to give the simplest implementation, what I am trying to achieve is a carousel view that 'snaps' to the center item, has peek insert showing about 20% of next item, but that when first loaded (so there's nothing to the 'left') the first item should be dead center on screen. By default, they do not look the same on iOS and Android so I'd have expected anyone could reproduce the 'error' just by making a simple carousel view wiht an image? I only added the grid above as part of my effort to make them equal but I failed so far

Comment: I find a similar sample, you could download from the blog for reference.https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/carouselview-xamarin-forms-4-3-prerelease/

Comment: That sample has exactly the problem I am describing - there is no item on android that is centred when the Sneek value is set.